# Flutter Xcode build produces error 'Parse issue: Module not found'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My flutter build runs on simulators perfectly fine through visual studio code, tried cleaning, reinstalling pods etc but no luck. When I wanted to Archive and do a build on any device I would always get a `'module not found'` error in the `GeneratedPluginRestraint.m`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you open the project in Xcode, you must open the `Runner.xcworkspace` instead of the `Runner.xcproj` file!

Comment: Why is that?  I used to be able to run my app in xcproj, but after rebuilding my ios folder I get the exact same error and can only run in xcworkspace.

Comment: Please make sure that your solution is actually working. There is no relation between your solution and the problem.